# How to call bean with @Autowiring from app context in security context

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

After a research, I still dont found a solution for this problem.

My aim is to validate user in Custom Authentication Provider using database but the @Autowiring always throw Null Pointer Exception.

Here my code:

Custom Authentication Provider:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private Validator iValidate;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException{         
        if (iValidate.userNameCheck(auth.getName()) != "00") {
            auth=null;
        }     
        return auth:            
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(auth));
    }

}
```

Validator.java:

```
@Component
public class Validator implements IsamSvc {

    private StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public String userNameCheck(String mercid, String caller) {

        /////validating code/////
    }   
}
```

Spring Security XML:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />



<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" >


    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession" session-authentication-error-url="/login.do?sessionalreadyexist">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.do?expired" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/clearcache" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/login.do?logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

 <form-login login-page='/login.do' login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/main" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login.do?error" username-parameter="username"    password-parameter="password" authentication-details-source-ref="CustomAuthInfoSource" /> -->

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="CustomAuthenticationProvider" class="xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
```

beans.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="iValidate" class="xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.Validator" scope="prototype" />

/////// Other beans ////////
```

when i call `@Autowired private Validator iValidate;` in @Controller class, it work normally,but in CustomAuthenticationProvider, it will return null ...

Any Solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

annotate the `CustomAuthenticationProvider` with `@Component` annotation

Comment: Still Throw null pointer,where the `<context:component-scan base-package="" />
 <context:annotation-config />` should be placed

Comment: this link will help https://sakaenakajima.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/spring-3-enable-annotation/